# The package at "node_modules/sharp/lib/utility.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "fs"

Tags: react-native, expo, sharp, expo-go

as i was trying to run my expo app in android studio virtual device. in expo go. i encountered a error in my terminal saying:

```
The package at "node_modules/sharp/lib/utility.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "fs".
It failed because the native React runtime does not include the Node standard library.
```

and when i try to debug it expo/webpack. this is showing up.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/sharp/lib/libvips.js:3
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
  1 | 'use strict';
  2 |
> 3 | const fs = require('fs');
  4 | const os = require('os');
  5 | const path = require('path');
  6 | const spawnSync = require('child_process').spawnSync;

ERROR in ./node_modules/sharp/lib/libvips.js:6
Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'
  4 | const os = require('os');
  5 | const path = require('path');
> 6 | const spawnSync = require('child_process').spawnSync;
  7 | const semverCoerce = require('semver/functions/coerce');
  8 | const semverGreaterThanOrEqualTo = require('semver/functions/gte');
  9 |

ERROR in ./node_modules/sharp/lib/utility.js:3
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
  1 | 'use strict';
  2 |
> 3 | const fs = require('fs');
  4 | const path = require('path');
  5 | const events = require('events');
  6 | const detectLibc = require('detect-libc');

ERROR in ./node_modules/sharp/node_modules/detect-libc/lib/detect-libc.js:6
Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'
  4 | 'use strict';
  5 |
> 6 | const childProcess = require('child_process');
  7 | const { isLinux, getReport } = require('./process');
  8 | const { LDD_PATH, readFile, readFileSync } = require('./filesystem');
  9 |

ERROR in ./node_modules/sharp/node_modules/detect-libc/lib/filesystem.js:6
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
  4 | 'use strict';
  5 |
> 6 | const fs = require('fs');
  7 |
  8 | /**
  9 |  * The path where we can find the ldd

web compiled with 5 errors
```

i try to fix this by installing: fs,  child_process using npm but it still there.

```
npm i fs
npm i child_process
```

then i try to follow some possible fix and it still there. like
adding this to package.json. its not fixed still

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "os": false,
    "path": false
  }
```

this is my repo. if you wanna checkout the source code.
https://github.com/jamilharun/CampusBytesMobile/tree/error

Answer (score 0):

`sharp-cli` is a CLI tool, you can't use it directly in your React Native code because it relies on `fs` package which is not present in the Hermes JS engine.

First, you need to remove this line from `LoginScreen.js`:

```
import constants from "sharp-cli/lib/constants";
```

Then reinstall `sharp-cli` as a development dependency (if you need this package at all):

```
npm install --save-dev sharp-cli
```